# Display resolution problem

Tags: display-resolution

after switching to kubuntu 22.04 from windows 11 on my laptop, connected display that worked well on 2560 x 1440 on windows, now on linux shows me only 1920x1080 option.
Can someone help me?

Edit:
Gpu: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU  2.60GHz

Terminal shows me this information about monitor which shows that 1440p resolution should be able:

```
40: None 00.0: 10002 LCD Monitor [Created at monitor.125] Unique ID: rdCR.Y_98S2YX844 Parent ID: _Znp.+bXFdTPniO1 
Hardware Class: monitor Model: "AOC Q27G2G3R3B" 
Vendor: AOC "AOC" Device: eisa 0x2702 "Q27G2G3R3B" 
Serial ID: "RTEN7HA017306" Resolution: 720x400@70Hz Resolution: 640x480@60Hz Resolution: 640x480@67Hz Resolution: 640x480@72Hz Resolution: 640x480@75Hz Resolution: 800x600@56Hz Resolution: 800x600@60Hz Resolution: 800x600@72Hz Resolution: 800x600@75Hz Resolution: 832x624@75Hz Resolution: 1024x768@60Hz Resolution: 1024x768@70Hz Resolution: 1024x768@75Hz Resolution: 1280x1024@75Hz Resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz Resolution: 1280x1024@60Hz Resolution: 640x480@100Hz Resolution: 640x480@120Hz Resolution: 2560x1440@60Hz 
Size: 597x336 mm 
Year of Manufacture: 2022 Week of Manufacture: 30 Detailed Timings #0: Resolution: 2560x1440 Horizontal: 2560 2608 2640 2720 (+48 +80 +160) +hsync Vertical: 1440 1443 1448 1481 (+3 +8 +41) +vsync Frequencies: 241.50 MHz, 88.79 kHz, 59.95 Hz Driver Info #0: Max. Resolution: 2560x1440 Vert. Sync Range: 48-144 Hz Hor. Sync Range: 30-230 kHz 
Bandwidth: 241 MHz Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown Attached to: #37 (VGA compatible controller)
```

**xandr:**

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1440     59.91  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600      119.97    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: We need to know what is the hardware.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Also pleas add output of `xrandr` to your question.

Comment: yes i installed them